# AngularJS: left join analog

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I use `left join` or `populate` analog in AngularJS? When page loads two API requests are done - `/api/books` and `/api/authors`. Books contain `author` id field, I want to show author's name instead of his id.

```
$scope.books = Book.query();
$scope.authors = Author.query();

<tr ng-repeat="book in books">
    <td>{{book.name}}</td>
    <td>{{book.author}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: why can't you do the join from the server side? Doing all your data processing on the client side is expensive.

Comment: Can you just use `authors[book.author].name`? (You may need to iterate over `$scope.authors` and build a hash on the scope that maps each author's ID to its value.)